# link against 'Current' version of Python.framework

Tags: xcode, macos, frameworks, linker

I have a binary where I link to the `Python.framework`.

Via `otool -L <binary>`, it seems that it links against the full symlink-resolved path, i.e. `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python` and not `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/Python`. From users which have only the Python 2.6 framework, I also got the report that it throws this error:

```
Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
  Referenced from: /Applications/MusicPlayer.app/Contents/MacOS/MusicPlayer
  Reason: image not found
```

How can I tell Xcode that it should link to `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/Python`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting-up the Target's *Link Binary with Libraries* allows you a number of different versions.  Use the *unversioned* `libpython.dyld` (top one):

[image]

Comment: I used libpython2.6.dylib as it makes testing easier. But thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot link to the "Current" version, as it may be updated to point to a newer version that fundamentally breaks the library interface that you're linking against.